# WebView dependency of autoLink?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

A user of my app reported that he is experiencing a crash when he disables Chrome or has an old WebView implementation installed. He recorded a logcat (see below) which seems to indicate that this comes from using `<TextView autoLink="all">` as there are some "linkify" calls in the stack trace.

Is this documented and correct? Is there anything I can do against this?

```
01-30 08:19:55.726 22028-22028/? E/WebViewFactory: error instantiating provider
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:208)
at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2530)
at android.webkit.WebView.findAddress(WebView.java:1802)
at android.text.util.Linkify.gatherMapLinks(Linkify.java:562)
at android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(Linkify.java:260)
at android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(Linkify.java:226)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5330)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5250)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1626)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:820)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:44)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:40)
at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:806)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:836)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at mono.android.TypeManager.n_activate(Native Method)
at mono.android.TypeManager.Activate(TypeManager.java:7)
at md5122bcb1b606efcbee085c8ccc5f780c2.EntryContentsView.<init>(EntryContentsView.java:30)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
at md5f0702f468598c68ce18586502249fb40.EntryActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at md5f0702f468598c68ce18586502249fb40.EntryActivity.onCreate(EntryActivity.java:36)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
01-30 08:19:55.731 22028-22028/? E/WebViewFactory:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load WebView
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.initialize(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:71)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.<init>(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:36)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForO.<init>(WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForO.java:4)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForOMR1.<init>(WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForOMR1.java:5)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForOMR1.create(WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForOMR1.java:1)
... 62 more
Caused by: org.chromium.base.library_loader.ProcessInitException
at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:91)
at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadNowOverrideApplicationContext(LibraryLoader.java:27)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.initialize(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:65)
... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libmonochrome.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:75)
... 68 more
01-30 08:19:55.762 22028-22028/? W/monodroid: Could not activate JNI Handle 0xffebbf18 (key_handle 0xd98043) of Java type 'md5122bcb1b606efcbee085c8ccc5f780c2/EntryContentsView' as managed type 'keepass2android.view.EntryContentsView'.
01-30 08:19:55.771 22028-22028/? W/monodroid: Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
01-30 08:19:55.773 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid: UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid: System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0xffebbf18 (key_handle 0xd98043) of Java type 'md5122bcb1b606efcbee085c8ccc5f780c2/EntryContentsView' as managed type 'keepass2android.view.EntryContentsView'. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class TextView ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class TextView ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load WebView ---> Java.Lang.Exception: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Exception' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.LinkageError: dlopen failed: "/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libmonochrome.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/chatty: uid=10335(keepass2android.keepass2android) identical 4 lines
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <2b267221e4bc410096484de99ce46573>:0 
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <d8acd8f3e3204c27aabdcd07a93e0012>:0 
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <d8acd8f3e3204c27aabdcd07a93e0012>:0 
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:   at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root) [0x00044] in <4d2cb53cea504752aa28076fde8f6158>:0 
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:   at keepass2android.view.EntryContentsView.InflateView () [0x00016] in <37f029d427ad47a7ae40edab8c35be11>:0 
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:   at keepass2android.view.EntryContentsView..ctor (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Util.IAttributeSet attrs) [0x00008] in <37f029d427ad47a7ae40edab8c35be11>:0 
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:     at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:cc1b1162-c604-473e-98cf-0a5108020a32 (intptr,object[])
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr signature_ptr, System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x000de] in <4d2cb53cea504752aa28076fde8f6158>:0 
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr typename_ptr, System.IntPtr signature_ptr, System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr parameters_ptr) [0x00167] in <4d2cb53cea504752aa28076fde8f6158>:0 
01-30 08:19:55.791 22028-22028/? I/MonoDroid:     at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:dd2cc4f8-4b75-4317-ac07-d1f2f711046e (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
01-30 08:19:55.795 22028-22028/? D/KP2A: System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0xffebbf18 (key_handle 0xd98043) of Java type 'md5122bcb1b606efcbee085c8ccc5f780c2/EntryContentsView' as managed type 'keepass2android.view.EntryContentsView'. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class TextView ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class TextView ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load WebView ---> Java.Lang.Exception: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Exception' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.LinkageError: dlopen failed: "/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libmonochrome.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: do you have a TextView that uses autoLink? It seems that the crash is reported to the aosp-project in Github but it doesn't say anything more.

Comment: yes, I have         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/entry_url"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/url_vdots"
            style="@style/EntryItem" />

Comment: yes I tried to reproduce your problem and also it happens on my side. The issue is on this class https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7e361d2/core/java/android/webkit/WebViewFactory.java at line 95. So I thought that a quick solution would be to catch the AndroidRuntimeException and just display a message to user that this action cannot be performed or navigate him to enable at least 1 browser in the device. I know its not a robust solution but that's what I can think right now